# Flex 4 Vslider track, top and bottom margin

Tags: flex4, slider, skinning

I have a Vslider in Flex 4 that I am skinning with images.  The image for the thumb makes it much larger and the track image  has some stuff at the top and the bottom that I do not want to be covered by the thumb when it is all the way at the top or bottom.  So, how do I create that margin so the range of the thumb on the track is shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying the thumb height to be larger than it really is in the skin for the vslider.

```
<!--- The default skin class is VSliderThumbSkin. 
        @copy spark.components.supportClasses.TrackBase#thumb
        @see spark.skins.spark.VSliderThumbSkin -->
<s:Button id="thumb" left="0" right="0" width="11" height="50"
    skinClass="your.thumb.skin.class"/>
```

The skin class has an image that is 25x25.  By making this class have a height of 50 it gives the thumb ~12px of padding on both top and bottom of the thumb.